# Python: multiply csv data together with dict()

Tags: python, csv

I posted below a code that works fine. What it does at the moment is:

it opens 2 `.csv` files 'CMF.csv' and 'D65.csv', and then
performs some math on it.

Here's the simple structure of those files :

'CMF.csv' (wavelength, x, y, z)

```
400,1.879338E-02,2.589775E-03,8.508254E-02
410,8.277331E-02,1.041303E-02,3.832822E-01
420,2.077647E-01,2.576133E-02,9.933444E-01
...etc
```

'D65.csv': (wavelength, a, b)

```
400,82.7549,14.708
410,91.486,17.6753
420,93.4318,20.995
...etc
```

I have a 3rd file `data.csv`, with this structure (serialNumber, wavelength, measurement, name) :

```
0,400,2.21,1
0,410,2.22,1
0,420,2.22,1
...
1,400,2.21,2
1,410,2.22,2
1,420,2.22,2
...etc
```

What I would like to do is to be able to write a few lines of code to perform
math on all the series of the last file (series are defined by their serial number and their name)

For example I need a loop that will perform, for each name or serial number, and for each wavelength, the operation:

`x * a * measurement`

I tried to load data.csv`in the csv reader as the other files, but I couldn't

any ideas?

Thanks

```
import csv

with open('CMF.csv') as cmf:
    reader = csv.reader(cmf)
    dict_cmf = dict()
    for row in reader:
        dict_cmf[float(row[0])] = row

with open('D65.csv') as d65:
    reader = csv.reader(d65)
    dict_d65 = dict()
    for row in reader:
        dict_d65[float(row[0])] = row

with open('data.csv') as sp:
    reader = csv.reader(sp)
    dict_sp = dict()
    for row in reader:
        dict_sp[float(row[0])] = row

Y = 0
Y_total = 0
X = 0
X_total = 0
Z = 0 
Z_total = 0
i = 0
j = 0


for i in range(400, 700, i+10):

    X = float(dict_cmf[i][1]) * float(dict_d65[i][1])
    X_total = X_total + X
    Y = float(dict_cmf[i][2]) * float(dict_d65[i][1])
    Y_total = Y_total + Y
    Z = float(dict_cmf[i][3]) * float(dict_d65[i][1]) 
    Z_total = Z_total + Z   


wp_X = 100 * X_total / Y_total
wp_Y = 100 * Y_total / Y_total
wp_Z = 100 * Z_total / Y_total

print Y_total
print "D65_CMF_2006_10_deg white point = "
print wp_X, wp_Y, wp_Z
```

I get this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\gary\Documents\eclipse\Spectro\1illum_XYZ2006_D65_numpy.py", line 24, in <module> dict_sp[row[0]] = row IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: what is your error when you try to load 'spectral_data.csv'? In your question you try to open 'spectral_data.csv' but call the file 'data.csv'.

Comment: hi, sorry for the names mismatch. I just edited the code and added loading data.csv with the same technique as the other files, I changed "a", "b" names to some numbers and keept float() The error I get is `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gary\Documents\eclipse\Spectro\1illum_XYZ2006_D65_numpy.py", line 24, in <module>
    dict_sp[row[0]] = row
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Add the traceback to your Q please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need pandas. You can read the files into pandas tables, then join them to replace your code with this code:

```
import pandas

cmf = pandas.read_csv('CMF.csv', names=['wavelength', 'x', 'y', 'z'])
d65 = pandas.read_csv('D65.csv', names=['wavelength', 'a', 'b'])
data = pandas.read_csv('data.csv', names=['serialNumber', 'wavelength', 'measurement', 'name'])

lookup = pandas.merge(cmf, d65, on='wavelength')
merged = pandas.merge(data, lookup, on='wavelength')

totals = ((lookup[['x', 'y', 'z']].T*lookup['a']).T).sum()
wps  = totals/totals['y']

print totals['y']
print "D65_CMF_2006_10_deg white point = "
print wps
```

Now, that doesn't do the last bit where you want to calculate extra values for each measurement. You can do this by adding a column to `merged`, like this:

```
merged['newcol'] = merged.x * merged.a * merged.measurement
```

Comment: this sounds like lots of fun, however the result of your code is not what's intended by mine: pseudocode for white point is for each wavelength do y * a = s, then add s to total_Y. Then do for all wavel. x * a = u and z * a = v, then add u to total_X and v to total_Z, then white point is X = total_X/Y  , Y = total_Y/Y, Z = total_Z/Z

Comment: I've changed the totals calculation to include multiplication by each associated a. Sorry about that. The above code does this for each wavelength in the first two files, using the associated a value. The rest of the calculation is as you describe.

Comment: where do you add this? `merged['newcol'] = merged.x * merged.a * merged.measurement`

Comment: You can just add in on the end. I would guess you would want a more descriptive name for whatever this product represents.

Comment: OK, I have a new poblem: how do I calculate this new result for sets of data exctracted from file `data.csv` with a serial number constraint? I.e. only compute for the series defined by serialNumber 0, 1, 2, etc. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435732/python-pandas-parsing-math-operations

Answer (score 1):

One or more of the lines in `data.csv` does not contain what you think it does. Try to put your statement inside a try...except block to see what the problem is:

```
with open('spectral_data.csv') as sp:
    reader = csv.reader(sp)
    dict_sp = dict()
    for row in reader:
        try:
            dict_sp[float(row[0])] = row
        except IndexError as e:
            print 'The problematic row is:'
            print row
            raise e
```

A proper debugger would also be helpful in these kind of situations.

---

[pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) is probably the better way to go, but if you'd like an example in vanilla Python, you can have a look at this example:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)
for fname, cols in [('CMF.csv', ('x', 'y', 'z')), ('D65.csv', ('a', 'b'))]:
    with open(fname) as ifile:
        reader = csv.reader(ifile)
        for row in reader:
            wl, values = int(row[0]), row[1:]
            d[wl].update(zip(cols, map(float, values)))

measurements = defaultdict(dict)
with open('data.csv') as ifile:
    reader = csv.reader(ifile)
    cols = ('measurement', 'name')
    for serial, wl, me, name in reader:
        measurements[int(serial)][int(wl)] = dict(zip(cols, (float(me), str(name))))

for serial in sorted(measurements.keys()):
    for wl in sorted(measurements[serial].keys()):
        me = measurements[serial][wl]['measurement']
        print me * d[wl]['x'] * d[wl]['a']
```

This will store both x, y, z, a and b in a dictionary inside a dictionary with wavelength as the key (there is no apparent reason to store these values in separate dicts).

The measurements are stored in a two level deep dictionary with keys `serial` and `wavelength`. This way you can iterate over all serials and all corresponding wavelength like shown in the latter part of the code.

---

As for your specific calculations on the data in your example, this can be done quite easily with this structure:

```
tot_x = sum(v['x']*v['a'] for v in data.values())
tot_y = sum(v['y']*v['a'] for v in data.values())
tot_z = sum(v['z']*v['a'] for v in data.values())

wp_x = 100 * tot_x / tot_y
wp_y = 100 * tot_y / tot_y # Sure this is correct? It will always be 100
wp_z = 100 * tot_z / tot_y

print wp_x, wp_y, wp_z # 798.56037811 100.0 3775.04316468
```

---

These are the dictionaries given the input file in your question:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(dict(data))
{400: {'a': 82.7549,
       'b': 14.708,
       'x': 0.01879338,
       'y': 0.002589775,
       'z': 0.08508254},
 410: {'a': 91.486,
       'b': 17.6753,
       'x': 0.08277331,
       'y': 0.01041303,
       'z': 0.3832822},
 420: {'a': 93.4318,
       'b': 20.995,
       'x': 0.2077647,
       'y': 0.02576133,
       'z': 0.9933444}}
>>> pprint(dict(measurements))
{0: {400: {'measurement': 2.21, 'name': '1'},
     410: {'measurement': 2.22, 'name': '1'},
     420: {'measurement': 2.22, 'name': '1'}},
 1: {400: {'measurement': 2.21, 'name': '2'},
     410: {'measurement': 2.22, 'name': '2'},
     420: {'measurement': 2.22, 'name': '2'}}}
```