# Python: pandas, parsing math operations

Tags: python, csv, pandas

somebody on stackoverflow adviced me to use pandas to label the values of my csv files and provided the code below:

```
# original code
import pandas

cmf = pandas.read_csv('CMF_MA68II.csv', names=['wavelength', 'x', 'y', 'z'])
d65 = pandas.read_csv('D65_MA68II_10nm.csv', names=['wavelength', 'a', 'b'])
data = pandas.read_csv('spectral_data.csv', names=['serialNumber', 'wavelength', 'measurement', 'name'])

lookup = pandas.merge(cmf, d65, on='wavelength')
merged = pandas.merge(data, lookup, on='wavelength')

totals = ((lookup[['x', 'y', 'z']].T*lookup['a']).T).sum()
wps  = 100 * totals/totals['y']

print totals['y']
print "D65_CMF_2006_10_deg white point = "
print wps
```

I added this part at the end:

```
# here's my crappy part:

i = 0

for i in range(i, i+1), data['serialNumber']:
    x = ((merged.x * merged.a * merged.measurement).sum() / (merged.y * merged.a * 100).sum())    
    y = ((merged.y * merged.a * merged.measurement).sum() / (merged.y * merged.a * 100).sum())    
    z = ((merged.z * merged.a * merged.measurement).sum() / (merged.y * merged.a * 100).sum())         
    print x, y, z
```

But these lines perform the operation on all the lines of my file regardless of the `name`associated with them, the result being an average of all separate measurements.

As you can see, the structure of the file `'spectral_data.csv'` is `names=['serialNumber', 'wavelength', 'measurement', 'name']`

What I'd like to do is to perform this operation :

```
merged['X'] = (merged.x * merged.a * merged.measurement).sum()/totals['y']
```

on series of data that are defined by their `name`, i.e., my file `'spectral_data.csv'` contains multiple series of values, and I'd like to get results for each one of them, and store them in a new file with a structure ['serial number', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'name']

Anybody has a solution for this?

Thanks

file examples:
'CMF_MA68II.csv'

```
400,1.879338E-02,2.589775E-03,8.508254E-02
410,8.277331E-02,1.041303E-02,3.832822E-01
420,2.077647E-01,2.576133E-02,9.933444E-01
430,3.281798E-01,4.698226E-02,1.624940E+00
440,4.026189E-01,7.468288E-02,2.075946E+00
450,3.932139E-01,1.039030E-01,2.128264E+00
460,3.013112E-01,1.414586E-01,1.768440E+00
470,1.914176E-01,1.999859E-01,1.310576E+00
480,7.593120E-02,2.682271E-01,7.516389E-01
490,1.400745E-02,3.554018E-01,3.978114E-01
500,5.652072E-03,4.780482E-01,2.078158E-01
510,3.778185E-02,6.248296E-01,8.852389E-02
520,1.201511E-01,7.788199E-01,3.784916E-02
530,2.380254E-01,8.829552E-01,1.539505E-02
540,3.841856E-01,9.665325E-01,6.083223E-03
550,5.374170E-01,9.907500E-01,2.323578E-03
560,7.123849E-01,9.944304E-01,8.779264E-04
570,8.933408E-01,9.640545E-01,3.342429E-04
580,1.034327E+00,8.775360E-01,1.298230E-04
590,1.147304E+00,7.869950E-01,5.207245E-05
600,1.148163E+00,6.629035E-01,2.175998E-05
610,1.048485E+00,5.282296E-01,9.530130E-06
620,8.629581E-01,3.950755E-01,0.000000E+00
630,6.413984E-01,2.751807E-01,0.000000E+00
640,4.323126E-01,1.776882E-01,0.000000E+00
650,2.714900E-01,1.083996E-01,0.000000E+00
660,1.538163E-01,6.033976E-02,0.000000E+00
670,8.281010E-02,3.211852E-02,0.000000E+00
680,4.221473E-02,1.628841E-02,0.000000E+00
690,2.025590E-02,7.797457E-03,0.000000E+00
700,9.816228E-03,3.776140E-03,0.000000E+00
```

'D65_MA68II_10nm.csv'

```
400,82.7549,14.708
410,91.486,17.6753
420,93.4318,20.995
430,86.6823,24.6709
440,104.865,28.7027
450,117.008,33.0859
460,117.812,37.8121
470,114.861,42.8693
480,115.923,48.2423
490,108.811,53.9132
500,109.354,59.8611
510,107.802,66.0635
520,104.79,72.4959
530,107.689,79.1326
540,104.405,85.947
550,104.046,92.912
560,100,100
570,96.3342,107.184
580,95.788,114.436
590,88.6856,121.731
600,90.0062,129.043
610,89.5991,136.346
620,87.6987,143.618
630,83.2886,150.836
640,83.6992,157.979
650,80.0268,165.028
660,80.2146,171.963
670,82.2778,178.769
680,78.2842,185.429
690,69.7213,191.931
700,71.6091,198.261
```

'spectral_data.csv'

```
0,400,12.73,"a"
0,410,12.41,"a"
0,420,12.55,"a"
0,430,13.42,"a"
0,440,15.07,"a"
0,450,17.31,"a"
0,460,19.20,"a"
0,470,20.96,"a"
0,480,22.11,"a"
0,490,23.45,"a"
0,500,24.62,"a"
0,510,25.42,"a"
0,520,24.51,"a"
0,530,22.43,"a"
0,540,20.94,"a"
0,550,21.59,"a"
0,560,22.36,"a"
0,570,21.54,"a"
0,580,22.03,"a"
0,590,28.86,"a"
0,600,37.02,"a"
0,610,42.00,"a"
0,620,44.79,"a"
0,630,46.57,"a"
0,640,47.56,"a"
0,650,48.70,"a"
0,660,49.90,"a"
0,670,50.75,"a"
0,680,51.53,"a"
0,690,52.24,"a"
0,700,53.00,"a"
1,400,2.31,"b"
1,410,2.33,"b"
1,420,2.33,"b"
1,430,2.30,"b"
1,440,2.29,"b"
1,450,2.30,"b"
1,460,2.27,"b"
1,470,2.26,"b"
1,480,2.24,"b"
1,490,2.23,"b"
1,500,2.22,"b"
1,510,2.21,"b"
1,520,2.20,"b"
1,530,2.19,"b"
1,540,2.18,"b"
1,550,2.18,"b"
1,560,2.18,"b"
1,570,2.16,"b"
1,580,2.15,"b"
1,590,2.14,"b"
1,600,2.14,"b"
1,610,2.13,"b"
1,620,2.12,"b"
1,630,2.11,"b"
1,640,2.11,"b"
1,650,2.11,"b"
1,660,2.10,"b"
1,670,2.08,"b"
1,680,2.07,"b"
1,690,2.06,"b"
1,700,2.04,"b"
```

Comment: Maybe I'm able to help you if you post some example data from your csv files, also I think your code have some errors check this line `for i in range(i, i+1), data['serialNumber']:`

Comment: I just added the files

Answer (score 1):

This will do that calculation into three new columns, then group by the name and serial number (you could actually group by either in this case, but this way you get both in the final result):

```
# First calculate the new columns
cols = ['x', 'y', 'z']
uppercols = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
for uppercol, col in zip(uppercols, cols):
    merged[uppercol] = (merged[col] * merged.a * merged.measurement)/totals['y']

# Now group and sum
sums = merged.groupby(['serialNumber', 'name'])[uppercols].sum()
```

To write that to a CSV file, just do

```
sums.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group and apply an user-defined function:

```
res =  merged.groupby(['serialNumber','name']).apply(lambda g:pd.Series([(g[c] * g.a * g.measurement).sum() / totals['y'] for c in "xyz"], index=['X','Y','Z']))
print res
```